# Getting the correct query in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to get this simple query to just get a subfield out of a collection. So far I just keep getting the entire field so what should I correct to just print out the subfield I'm looking for?

I'm trying to list the titles (only) of all movies with a rank of less than 9.2 and with at least 5 votes, print the titles in alphabetical order.

This is my query so far but its incorrect and just returns the whole object. How can I get it to return just the rank and votes of Jungle Book? Thank you very much in advance.

db.collections.find({"title": {$exists:true}}, {"_id":0, "rank":{$lt : 9.2}})

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("10"), "rank" : 6, "votes" : 8.8, "title" : "Jungle Book" }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("11"), "rank" : 8, "votes" : 8.7, "title" : "Spawn" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the filter/query all in the first parameter. The second parameter is a set of booleans for which properties it should return.

```
db.ratings.find({title: {$exists:true}, rank:{$lt : 9.2}, 
    votes: {$gte : 5 } }, {_id:0, title:1}).sort({title:1})
```

This will return a set that looks like this:

```
[{"title" : "Jungle Book"}, {"title" : "Spawn"}]
```

If you want only the titles, and not in object form you could use "distinct" here:

```
db.ratings.distinct('title', {title: {$exists:true}, 
   rank:{$lt : 9.2}, votes: {$gte : 5 } });
```

The distinct query should be sorted by default. If you want to sort it a different way you'll need to use an aggregate query.

I've run this EXACT set of code against my local install:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.8
connecting to: test
rs0:PRIMARY> db.ratings.insert({rank:6, votes:8.8, title:"Jungle Book"});
rs0:PRIMARY> db.ratings.insert({rank:8, votes:8.7, title:"Spawn"});
rs0:PRIMARY> db.ratings.find({title: {$exists:true}, rank:{$lt : 9.2}, votes: {$gte : 5 } }, {_id:0, title:1}).sort({title:1})
{ "title" : "Jungle Book" }
{ "title" : "Spawn" }
rs0:PRIMARY> db.ratings.distinct('title', {title: {$exists:true}, rank:{$lt : 9.2}, votes: {$gte : 5 } });
[ "Jungle Book", "Spawn" ]
rs0:PRIMARY>
```

Comment: I tried to do it your way but the query returned nothing. Its saying that there were no results with the rank $lt 9.2 and votes $gte 5.

Comment: Thanks! I got it now. I had an error wrong on my part. Thank you very much for your help.